# Why use gulp-load plugin instead of gulp.task()?

Tags: npm, gulp

Can someone explain what is the difference(pros/cons) between:

I have in *path/to/module js* file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('task1', function(){...});
gulp.task('task2', function(){...});

module.exports = gulp;
```

Why use this (another plugin):

```
require('gulp-load')(gulp);

gulp.loadTasks('path/to/module'); // file containing gulp tasks
```

...
instead of this:

```
var gulp_other_tasks = require('path/to/module');
gulp.task('default', ['gulp_other_tasks'],'path/to/module');
```

**Legends:**

*gulp plugin*: any node_module that starts with a `gulp-...`

*gulp task*: any task created by `gulp.task(...)` method.

Comment: The idea behind loading tasks is to have a Grunt-like abstraction, or to make gulp more 'grunt-like'. A note on gulp-load: https://github.com/popomore/gulp-load/issues/1

Comment: @SteveLacy thanks for your response! I have a follow-up question: what good is `Grunt`-like abstraction for? in other words, I am trying to ask:  other than familiar syntax for `Grunt` users does it serve other purpose which is not apparent to me?

Comment: The plugin `gulp-load-plugins` would be the most useful abstractor, as it allows you to 'load' (require) all the plugins prefixed with 'gulp-' into an object without needing to manually add the require('gulp-plugin') in your gulpfile. 
https://github.com/jackfranklin/gulp-load-plugins#usage
That one is quire more useful (IMO as I am a code over config fanatic)

Comment: Would you like for me to post the comment as an answer?

Comment: There's a difference between loading *tasks* from some other file and loading *plugins*.  gulp-load-plugins is for the latter.  It looks like the options in the OP are about loading former.

Comment: @stu.salsbury thanks for your response! From the [API here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-load) it appears `gulp-load` can load tasks(gulp tasks defined as `gulp.task('task-name',function())// run example in my question` from some file **as well as** `npm` modules.

Comment: @SteveLacy thanks again! I think the `abstraction` (i.e. being able to load gulp tasks defined in a file or any external gulp module defined in node_modules alike) and  makes sense to me. However, I see you mention about `gulp-load-plugins`...I was asking about `gulp-load` :)  ...I admit it is not hard to get confused with module names